# Eloquent: Order by sum of two columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My working SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM news_tags  
ORDER BY  (link_clicks+views) DESC
```

What I've tried so far in eloquent is like this:

```
$newsTagSaved = NewsTag::
                orderBy(DB::raw("`views` + `link_clicks`"), 'desc')
                ->paginate(12)
                ->pluck('post_id');
```

Newstag table has many columns and views and link_clicks are two of them. Now, I'm trying to retrieve the post_id order by desc of sum of views and link_click.

How can I do it in Laravel eloquent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$newsTagSaved = NewsTag::select(DB::raw('views + link_clicks as score'))
    ->orderBy('score', 'desc')
    ->get();
dd($newsTagSaved);
```

This will return just `score` value. If you want to return other fields, simply add them to `select`. As an example:

```
$newsTagSaved = NewsTag::select(
    DB::raw('views + link_clicks as score'),
    'title',
    'created_at'
)
    ->orderBy('score', 'desc')
    ->get();
dd($newsTagSaved);
```